# Finding nth power of a 4 state Markov Chain Matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I am required to find P$_{ij}^{(n)}$ for the P matrix of a 4 state Markov chain with states 0,1,2,3 as given below

$\begin{matrix} 1-p&&p&&0&&0\\0&&1-p&&p&&0\\0&&0&&1-p&&p\\0&&0&&0&&1\end{matrix}$

There were two options. One was to solve it by finding eigenvalues and then left and right eigenvectors...etc. Second choice was to use method of generating function

P(s) = I+sP+s$^2$P$^2$+s$^3$P$^3$...........

I chose to use the second method and got the  (I-sP)$^{-1}$ as under:

\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{ps-s+1}&&\frac{-ps}{(ps-s+1)^2}&&\frac{p^2s^2}{(ps-s+1)^3}&&\frac{p^3s^3}{(s-1)(ps-s+1)^3}\\0&&\frac{1}{ps-s+1}&&\frac{-ps}{(ps-s+1)^2}&&\frac{-p^2s^2}{(s-1)(ps-s+1)^2}\\0&&0&&\frac{1}{ps-s+1}&&\frac{ps}{(s-1)(ps-s+1)}\\0&&0&&0&&\frac{-1}{(s-1)}\end{matrix}

Now to gather the coefficients of $s^n$ in each of the terms, I could do it for all terms of the inverse matrix except terms $a_{14}$, $a_{24}$ and $a_{34}$.

(a)    Could I please get guidance to do this?

(b)   Is there any other easier method to calculate the P$_{ij}^{(n)}$?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, but once you have formulas for $P^{(n)}_{ij}$ for $j=1,2,3$, you can simply write $P^{(n)}_{i4}=1-\sum_{j=1}^3 P^{(n)}_{ij}.$

Comment: The coefficients for $s^n$ for most of the terms in the inverse matriX are easy as we just need to find the nth term in $ (ps-s+1) ^{-1}$, (n-1) th term in $(ps-s+1)^{-2}$ etc....but I have not been able to get the coefficients for the terms as mentioned earlier . Also id there any other simpler method to find $p^n$?

Comment: Auto-duplicate? Tsk, tsk, tsk...

Comment: Yes, the related question was asked by me... I could not get an answer, so tried to plod my way through.... managed to get the coefficients for negative exponents for binomial expansions of single brackets, but now I am stuck when we multiply this by (s-1)